# Any reference to use JavaDB in Spring3.0?

Tags: spring, pom.xml, derby, classnotfoundexception, javadb

I am trying to use JavaDB(apache derby) in Spring framework.
I found bunch of derby sample codes from web and it works nice. However, every code that I found were not using spring framework.

I want to use derby in spring like the way which does not uses Connection Interface and PreparedStatement. So is there any good sample using derby in Spring?

P.S.
furthermore, I put 'derby.jar' file to "src/main/webapp/resouces" but it can not find the reference.(Error message is ClassNotFoundException) So I added 'javadb : 10.9.1.0 : zip' to pom.xml(which means Maven) but it still does not work. Any idea will be welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's your problem exactly ? 
Post your stack trace here.
if you are using maven , post your pom.xml . 
There is no different to use spring or another framework. In fact they are irrelevant .
Did you added derby dependency to your pom ?

```
         <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
<artifactId>derby</artifactId>
<version>10.9.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Actually, at that time I did not have any ideas about the concept 'In-Memory Database'. But now, I can see what was my problem and fixed. I added Spring-jdbc to pom.xml and use <jdbc:> namespace in root-context.xml. more specifically, <jdbc:embedded-database>. In conclusion, setting derby with spring needs 1.add jar file to project, 2. add spring-jdbc to pom.xml, 3. add spring:jdbc embedded-database to root-context.xml. I did not use your way(adding dependency), Anyway Thanks for your answer.